# Hyperledger Fabric - change max_message_count configuration update "Error Validating Delta Set" following tutorial

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm executing tutorials on Hyperledger Fabric First Network (version 1.4) and I get an unexpected error when trying to change max_message_count variable from 10 to 20 in channel configuration.

I'm using this tutorial: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/channel_update_tutorial.html

Obviously, I don't change the Org list to the channel as in tutorial, I only change the parameter:

```
cat config.json | sed 's/"max_message_count": 10/"max_message_count": 20/g' > new_config.json
```

Then I Execute the encoding of new and old configuration in protobuffer, compute update, decode update to json, added envelope and recode envelope to protobuffer. It is okay.

Then I sign the update with both organization and tries to update, but it gives me this error:

```
Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- error authorizing update: error validating DeltaSet: policy for [Value]  /Channel/Orderer/BatchSize not satisfied: Failed to reach implicit threshold of 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining
```

This is the decoded update, as you can see is signed by both Org1MSP and Org2MSP: https://controlc.com/486d638a

These are the logs from orderer:

```
2020-12-10 17:28:04.282 UTC [cauthdsl] deduplicate -> WARN 01c De-duplicating identity [Org2MSPd2b5a4f881b520ad90a0ae5db7bd0b5362fae2d5916d972751da9bd35fb97f9b] at index 2 in signature set
2020-12-10 17:28:04.282 UTC [orderer.common.broadcast] ProcessMessage -> WARN 01d [channel: mychannel] Rejecting broadcast of config message from 172.20.0.7:56874 because of error: error authorizing update: error validating DeltaSet: policy for [Value]  /Channel/Orderer/BatchSize not satisfied: Failed to reach implicit threshold of 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining
```

Answer (score 0):

Self-Answer.
This type of modification needs the sign of the orderer:

```
export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=orderer.example.com:7050
export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/users/Admin\@example.com/msp/
peer channel signconfigtx -f org3_update_in_envelope.pb 
export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
peer channel update -f org3_update_in_envelope.pb -c $CHANNEL_NAME -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls --cafile $ORDERER_CA
```